From which university did Riemann acquired Ph.D?
Did Riemann get a Ph.D from the University of Berlin? Or did Riemann get his Ph.D from the University of Göttingen? I thought he had acquired it from the University of Berlin, but when I found out that his doctoral advisor was Gauss, I had doubts.

Math genealogy says Bernhard Riemann received the
Dr. phil. degree in 1851 from
Georg-August-Universität, Göttingen.
His advisor was C. F. Gauß .
Dissertation title: "Grundlagen für eine allgemeine Theorie der Funktionen einer veränderlichen complexen Größe"
Trans: "Foundations for a general theory of functions of a variable complex quantity"

A scan of Riemann's PhD thesis is available via Google. According to the cover page the defense took place on December 16, 1851.

Your translation of the thesis title is very literal. In modern language one could also say 'of a complex variable' without changing the intended meaning.

I assumed that "variable complex quantity" would be more in tune with the (minimal) previous use of complex numbers as of 1851.
